# How to detect autofilters in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

I am just wandering how to detect and turn off autofilter for worksheet in excel, using xlsxwriter, if not using other python library

I search for the documentation but could not really find one that points to detection but turning off it, I can thinking of

```
worksheet.autofilter("")
```

Does this work?

REgards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub loop_workbooks_for_loop()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws_num As Integer

Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet
ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.count

For i = 1 To ws_num
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
       ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Next

starting_ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I would need it in python..unless u are telling me to use python to execute VBA code

Comment: Yes it's usually what I do when xlsxwriter library give me trouble.
(https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html)
Might not be the best solution but it works =)